# Wine 1.9.24 on Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, wine

### The problem

When I try to start any windows program I get no error and nothing happens. I tried on 3 different machines with Centos 7. Also tried older versions of Wine. Tested with winbox.exe from Mikrotik and with putty.exe. What could be the problem?

```
$ ./wine winbox.exe
$
```

#### CentOS 7 version

```
$ cat /etc/*elease | grep "release" | head -1
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

#### Kernel version

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

#### Openbox version

```
$ openbox --version | grep "Openbox"
Openbox 3.5.2
```

### Wine install steps

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install -y libX11-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel libxcb-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libjpeg-devel gnutls-devel flex bison

cd /tmp
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/1.9/wine-1.9.24.tar.bz2
tar xjf wine-1.9.24.tar.bz2
cd wine-1.9.24

./configure  --enable-win64
make -j4
```

and the executable is working

```
$ ./wine --version
wine-1.9.24
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: ok http://superuser.com/questions/1161692/wine-1-9-24-and-centos-7

Comment: have you tried:
'sudo wine winbox.exe'

Comment: @Arash No, don't do that. Wine does not need to run as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### wine-2.0-rc3

Had no time to try the latest Wine 2.0 version, but all my problems are gone with wine-2.0-rc3. Tested only 32bit install. Step by step:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install -y libX11-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel libxcb-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libjpeg-devel gnutls-devel flex bison
sudo yum install -y samba-winbind samba-winbind-clients samba-winbind-modules libwbclient-devel mod_auth_ntlm_winbind
# OpenGL support
sudo yum install mesa-dri-drivers.i686 mesa-libGL.i686

mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/2.0/wine-2.0-rc3.tar.bz2
tar xjf wine-2.0-rc3.tar.bz2 && cd wine-2.0-rc3

# run provided install tool and write the output to file
./tools/wineinstall | tee output.file

# get the winetricks tool
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
WINE=~/bin/wine-2.0-rc3/wine sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6 mfc40 ie8 ie7

# start the downloaded windows program
./wine ~/Downloads/winbox.exe
```

### winbox from Mikrotik

[image: winbox]

### SketchUp

[image: winbox]